# Running another test case automatically in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I have three test cases inside one project in Selenium IDE

- Info test case that store all the login detail (username, password
  and email),
- 01Updating test case that update user profile
- 02Checking test case that check the user profile.

[image]

Both 01Updating and 02Checking require username and password from Info test case to login.

I want to run 02Checking automatically after 01Updating but 02Checking cannot access the username and password from Info case every time when it about to run (pls look at the above pic for the order). I usually have to delete or comment 01Updating in order to run 02Checking properly.

Is there a way to run all of them at one time without doing that in Selenium IDE?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure(because I don't know how variables is used in *01Updating* test), but I think you probably change values of 'username', 'password' and 'email' variables during 01Updating test, so when *02Checking* starts variables are not like in *01Updating* test.
It is happened because variables in these tests are global.

To solve this problem you should find in *01Updating* test commands that change value of 'username', 'password' and 'email' variables and replace them with another variables.